# Am I legally allowed to offset the tax I pay on freelance work? (UK)

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, tax-deduction, self-employment

I am currently employed full-time in the UK as a graphic designer, I have a salary of £30K, I have also registered myself as a sole trader as I occasionally take on freelance work in my spare time (designing logos and artwork for print and web) I bring in no more than £3K a year from this extra work, this work is completed from a room in my house using my own equipment.

Currently 20% of the £3K income is deducted as tax, am I legally allowed to offset this against anything related to this work? For example Electricity bills or equipment?

Thanks you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can deduct from your taxable profits (almost) any expenses incurred in the course of your business. See [here](https://www.gov.uk/expenses-if-youre-self-employed/overview) for HMRC's detailed advice on the subject. The fact that you have salaried PAYE employment as well makes no difference.

Comment: HMRC may consider £3K income to be a hobby and hence not allow the cost of computers etc to be deducted.  (So can't offset the cost of a new mac every year.)

Comment: @Ian But if they regard it as a hobby then the £3K of income is not taxable at all.

Comment: The income can be taxable as it is income from a trade, but using equipment that the HMRC says was brought for the hobby.    So if only 10% of the mac usage is for the trade, don't try to claim 100% of the cost of buying it.